# Is there an implicit independence assumption in Bayesian inference between X and parameters?

Tags: regression, bayesian, prior, posterior, supervised-learning

I often see things like
$$ p(w|X,y) \propto p(y|X,w) p(w)$$

where $w\in\mathbb R^p$ denotes some parameters, $y\in \mathbb R^n$ denotes some observed outcome values, and $X\in \mathbb R^{n\times d}$ denotes the matrix of observed inputs. But strictly following Bayes rule, isn't it

$$ p(w|X,y) \propto p(y|X,w) p(X|w) p(w)$$

or

$$ p(w|X,y) \propto p(y|X,w) p(w|X) $$
?

Is there an implicit independence assumption between $w$ and $X$? If so why is it justified?

Comment: yes, when $\mathbf{X}$ is considered a constant, as it often is, it's misleading to place it right next to $\mathbf{y}$ as only the latter is truly a random variable which is being conditioned upon. We do it anyways to help with our job security ;)

Comment: If $\mathbf{X}$ is constant, I can't see any difference, other than philosophical, between $p\left(\omega\right)$ and $p\left(\omega\,|\,\mathbf{X}\right)$. Of course, next time your $\mathbf{X}$ might be different, and you might have to change your prior, but this seems to be on a more *meta* level. So I would say your last expression is the correct one, and the first one is equivalent if $\mathbf{X}$ is constant for the purposes of modelling